# django-haystack problem when saving query in session

Tags: python, django, session-variables, django-haystack

I want to save the user input in my view, I don't know how to do it redefining the searchview so I did this:

```
  request.session['q']=request.GET.get('q')
  from haystack.views import SearchView
  search_view = SearchView(template = template_name)
  return search_view(request)
```

but I got this error:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):

   File "/home/usu/mysites/gondor/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 280, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)

   File "/home/usu/mysites/gondor/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 674, in __call__
    return self.application(environ, start_response)

   File "/home/usu/mysites/gondor/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 245, in __call__
    response = middleware_method(request, response)

   File "/home/usu/mysites/gondor/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/middleware.py", line 36, in process_response
    request.session.save()

   File "/home/usu/mysites/gondor/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/db.py", line 57, in save
    session_data = self.encode(self._get_session(no_load=must_create)),

   File "/home/usu/mysites/gondor/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/base.py", line 88, in encode
    pickled = pickle.dumps(session_dict, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)

   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/haystack/models.py", line 175, in __getstate__   del(ret_dict['searchsite'])

KeyError: 'searchsite'
```

If I remove the line:

```
 request.session['q']=request.GET.get('q')
```

the search works ok, I don't know if there is a problem with haystack or I'm doing something wrong.
Thanks.

Comment: Did you try reindexing? (The standard question for KeyErrors with Haystack)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the problem. In another view I was saving in the session the result of a SerchQuerySet, but the problem didn't raised at the time I've put the content but it raised when I've put other thing in the session. This was very difficult to find out.